# npm doesn't install dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

I've downloaded Bootstrap [sources](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/) form their official site, and then I tried to compile them myself. But when I run `npm-install` from the root of the project (where `package.json` is) I find that I miss some dependencies, for example:

for module `read-pkg-up` in its `package.json` (which is in `bootstrap-4.1.0\node_modules\read-pkg-up`) there are several dependencies listed:

```
"dependencies": {
    "find-up": "^1.0.0",
    "read-pkg": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

But the directory structure is

[image]

so there's no `read-pkg` folder dependency, but there's some other `path-exists` folder.

AFAIK npm should duplicate dependencies of every module (even if A depends on B and C depends on B then both copies of B should be saved in corresponding `node_modules` folders)

I've also tried deleting top level npm_modules and reinstalling, and even disabling `package-lock` with `npm config set package-lock false`.

The npm version is `5.6.0.`

Answer (score 0):

Have you flagged the dependencies with

```
—save
```

?

Answer (score 0):

ok, looks like what was happening is described in this part of npm docs, so there's no need to create unnecessary nested `node_modules` forlders, if one is already present somewhere on top

> Consider the case above, where foo -> bar -> baz. Imagine if, in
>   addition to that, baz depended on bar, so you'd have: foo -> bar ->
>   baz -> bar -> baz .... However, since the folder structure is:
>   foo/node_modules/bar/node_modules/baz, there's no need to put another
>   copy of bar into .../baz/node_modules, since when it calls
>   require("bar"), it will get the copy that is installed in
>   foo/node_modules/bar.
>
> This shortcut is only used if the exact same version would be
>   installed in multiple nested node_modules folders. It is still
>   possible to have a/node_modules/b/node_modules/a if the two "a"
>   packages are different versions. However, without repeating the exact
>   same package multiple times, an infinite regress will always be
>   prevented.